# Can a instance method in a Javascript subclass call it's parents static method?

Tags: javascript

This doesn't work. Is there a way for a child class in JS to have access to its parents static methods?

```
class Person {
    constructor() {}

    static isHuman() {
        return 'yes I am';
    }
}


class Brian extends Person {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    greeting() {
        console.log(super.isHuman())
    }
}

const b = new Brian();
b.greeting();
```

Comment: No, is not possible. It doesn't make sense.  You need to understand how the static members work.  read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. You can use `super` but to get at the static method you have to access the constructor property of it:

```
super.constructor.isHuman()
```

You can also use the class name directly:

```
Person.isHuman();
//this works because Brian inherits the static methods from Person
Brian.isHuman();
```

Or by going up the prototype chain

```
//would be referencing Brian
this.constructor.isHuman();
//would be referencing Person
this.__proto__.constructor.isHuman();
Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.isHuman();
```

---

Demo

```js
class Person {
  constructor() {}
  static isHuman() {
    return 'yes I am';
  }
}

class Brian extends Person {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }
  greeting() {
    console.log("From super: ", super.constructor.isHuman())
    console.log("From class name (Brian): ", Brian.isHuman())
    console.log("From class name (Person): ", Person.isHuman())
    console.log("From prototype chain: ", this.constructor.isHuman())
    console.log("From prototype chain: ", Object.getPrototypeOf(this).constructor.isHuman())
  }
}

const b = new Brian();
b.greeting();
```

Answer (score 0):

For static methods, use the class name rather than super.

```js
class Person {
    constructor() {}

    static isHuman() {
        return 'yes I am';
    }
}


class Brian extends Person {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

    greeting() {
        console.log(Person.isHuman())
    }
}

const b = new Brian();
b.greeting();
```